# Describe the language accepted by this NFA and convert it to DFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I met a question that asked me 'Describe the language accepted by this NFA and convert it to DFA'. The question is: (sorry for my lazy but the picture is difficult to draw...)
[image: question image]
From the first I got confused for why it isn't a DFA?? I did not see any state has simultaneously pointed a(or b) to two states...
Q(1), it is easy.
Q(2), from observation, I guess it is $a^\ast b\vert\left(a^\ast\left(ba\right)^\ast\right)^\ast$ 
Q(3), I use a traditional list method to convert this 'NFA' to DFA, but failed. So I have to draw a $\varepsilon-NFA$ from the Q(2)'s regular expression $a^\ast b\vert\left(a^\ast\left(ba\right)^\ast\right)^\ast$ I concluded, and then convert this $\varepsilon-NFA$ to DFA, like the following picture shows. But it seems that this result is still a NFA..

[image]

Could you please give me some hints or comments to this question? Thank you!

Comment: It is not a DFA because in state $q_1$, reading $b$, the automaton has nowhere to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The NFA accepts a lot of strings, so think about what kinds of strings it *doesn't* accept. Then try to build a DFA around that.

EDIT: I guess I should elaborate a bit. This is not a general strategy, but in this case, we notice in b) that the language consists of strings that don’t contain $bb$ as a substring. We can build a DFA to accept *only* strings containing $bb$ as a substring. Then flip accepting/rejecting states and we have what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answering @marcelgoh, but I got stuck again for the (bb)*... And my teacher did not teach me the rejecting states and the flip method... If you have time, could you give me a simple example for it?

Comment: Oh I guess I know what you mean, I will have a try... By the way the -1 is not voted by me QAQ.

Comment: No problem! It is equivalent to just fixing the NFA by adding a $b$-transition from $q_1$ to a new "garbage" state that always rejects (i.e. has a loop that stays there).

Comment: Incidentally, I just reread this and you're not looking for $(bb)^*$. You want to accept/reject $(a|b)^*bb(a|b)^*$, which is the language of strings containing the substring $bb$.

Comment: Em... yes, but I finally still use your second suggestion to add a garbage state to build the NFA, convert to DFA, and simplify DFA... and have got the answer. I have no idea how to reverse the  easier version(that DFA do not accept). Anyway, you teach me a big lesson on how to fix an uncompleted NFA, thank you my friend.

Comment: Glad it helped! To reverse a DFA, just change all accepting states to rejecting, and all rejecting states to accepting. Because the automaton still follows the exact same path, this new automaton accepts when and only when the old one rejected.

Comment: Dear @marcelgoh, I am sorry to disturb you again. But last night when I reviewed this question I found my past answer (using my method above) is wrong because I missed one more type of language this 'NFA' can describe ... And as I reviewed our talk again I got sparked: Could I just add an additional state $q2$ as garbage  state for the original diagram, and let $(q1,b)$ direct $q2$ and let $(q2,a)=(q2,b)=q2$ ? Though it seems too simple but after that this 'NFA' should have been a 'DFA' if I am not wrong...

Comment: @PeterNova Yes, this is all you had to do! You could arrive at this answer a number of ways. One of them is to just see what the NFA is missing (in this case it's simple). Another is to realise that this NFA rejects a really simple language of strings, so just take the complement. And the last method is the general one that you were probably taught in class, with new DFA states representing subsets of states in the old NFA.