# How to draw a DFA for (a|ba)(a|ba)*

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I met a question concerning draw a DFA for $\left(a\vert ba\right)\left(a\vert ba\right)^\ast$.
I firstly tried to expand the regular expression to a $\varepsilon$-NFA, then plan to transform it to a DFA. However, I feel there is something wrong when I expand $\left(ba\right)^\ast$. Because when I use the closure method to convert my $\varepsilon$-NFA to DFA, some states could not accept b, so even I draw the 'DFA', it may be not the correct DFA.
So is it a normal situation under this $\left(ba\right)^\ast$ condition? Or it is because where I got wrong? Please tell me if you have any thoughts, thank you!
The following is what I have tried for your kind reference.
[image: my trying]

Comment: Hi, as I said in the same question that you posted a while ago, all you need to do is to add a "reject" state to $q_1$ that rejects any strings with $bb$ in them ($q_1$, reading $b$, goes to $q_2$ which is non-accepting, and q_2, reading anything, stays in $q_2$). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324704/describe-the-language-accepted-by-this-nfa-and-convert-it-to-dfa/3324710#3324710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. The double circled state is the only accept state. The start state is the one with a nondescript arrow going into it.

[image]

As you can see, once two $b$'s follow each other directly, we go to the lower right state, from which no escape is possible. Any other string that is nonempty and ends with an $a$ gets accepted.